# jquery see if any boxes checked

Tags: jquery, html, forms

How do I find out if the users have checked any of the boxes with jQuery? Thanks.

```
<div id="boxes">
<input id='id1' type='checkbox'>
<input id='id2' type='checkbox'>
<input id='id3' type='checkbox'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [checked selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/checked) will select all checkboxes.

```
// Selector for all checked checkboxes.
var checkboxes = $("input:checked");
```

If you just want to know if any of them are checked, or how many, check the length of the selector.  If it's > 0, at least one checkbox is selected.  However, if you only want one box checked at a time, consider using a radio button instead (which also uses the checked selector).

```
var count = $("input:checked").length;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var checked = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var anychecked = 0 < $('#boxes :checkbox:checked').length();
```